# How can I explain each word in 「想過過過兒過過的生活」

Tags: sentence-structure

I know it's just a meme, but how to explain the structure of this setence:

> 小龍女深情的對楊過說：「我好想過過過兒過過的生活啊！」

Comment: Maybe we can put two more 過 in this meme and change it to "我也想過過過過兒過過的過去啊" --by looking at the wording, some might think she's stuttering

Comment: Why are there three 過 before 過兒? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: [1. 我也想過][2.過過][3. 過兒][4. 過過的][5. 過去][6. 啊] = [1. I had thought about][2. going through] [5. the past that] [3. 過兒][4. had gone through][6. 啊]

Answer (score 3):

小龍女(the subject)

深情的 (adv)

對楊過說 - said to 楊過 (the object)

> 我好想(過過) = I really want to (briefly go through)

> 過兒 (the person she speaks to)

> 過過的 = who had gone through

> 生活 = life

> 啊 (exclamation)

The first 過過 is a reduplication of the verb 過 to indicate 'slightly' or 'briefly' e.g. 去 = go; 去去 = go (briefly)

the second 過過 is the verb 過(go through) followed by a verb particle 過 that indicates "past perfect" e.g. 去 = go to; 去過 = had visited

> 「我好想過過過兒過過的生活啊！」=  " I really want to go through (experience) the life that you (過兒) had gone through (experienced)

She was speaking to 楊過 but didn't use the second-person from "you" to address him. Instead, she used 楊過's pet name 過兒 (third-person form)

Answer (score 2):

我好想**過過**(to experience/live)**過兒**(nickname of 楊過)**過過的**(had experienced/lived)生活(living)啊!

How wish am I to experience/live the living 過兒(he) had experienced/lived.